# How to bind CommandParameter on a longlistselector control

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, mvvm, windows-phone-8

am working on a windows phone 8 project that is using the mvvm pattern. I have a LongListSelector  as one of my controls on the view and it is  bound to a list of Answers. When a user selects an answer from the list a parameter has to be sent to the viewmodel in order to verify whether the selected answer is correct or not. The problem i have is what to specify as the command parameter, i have tried the selectedItem but it sends null to the view model. Any assistance is appreciated.

here is my xaml

```
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="WhiteSmoke">
                <Image Height="100" Width="100" Source="{Binding CurrentQuestion.Graphic}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentQuestion.Statement}" FontSize="30" Foreground="Black" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel>
                <phone:LongListSelector  
                    ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentQuestion.Answers}"
                    SelectionChanged="LongListSelector_SelectionChanged"
                    x:Name="Answers"

                    >                              

                    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,10,0,17" Background="{Binding  Status, Converter={StaticResource StatusConverter}}" >
                                <Button 
                                    Content="{Binding Text}"
                                    Height="100"
                                    Width="auto"
                                    Foreground="Black"
                                    FontSize="18"
                                    Command="{Binding ElementName=Answers, Path=DataContext.ProcessQuestionCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding  Path=ItemTemplate.Selecteditem}"

                                    />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector>
            </StackPanel>

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

and here is  part of my viewmodel

```
 public ICommand ProcessQuestionCommand 
    {
        get
        {
            if (_processQustionCommand==null)
            {
                _processQustionCommand = new RelayCommand<int>(ProcessQuestion, CanProcessQuestion);
            }
            return _processQustionCommand; 
        }
    }

public ICommand ProcessQuestionCommand 
    {
        get
        {
            if (_processQustionCommand==null)
            {
                _processQustionCommand = new RelayCommand<int>(ProcessQuestion, CanProcessQuestion);
            }
            return _processQustionCommand; 
        }
    }

    private bool CanProcessQuestion(int answerId)
    {
        //int answerId = Convert.ToInt32(answerIdStr);
        if (answerId> CurrentQuestion.Answers.Count()-1)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (CurrentQuestion.Answers[answerId].Status!=AnswerStatus.UNANSWERED)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void ProcessQuestion(int answerId)
    {
        //int answerId = Convert.ToInt32(answerIdStr);

        int correctAns = _currentQuestion.GetRightAnswer();
        if (answerId != correctAns)
        {
            _currentQuestion.Answers[answerId].Status = AnswerStatus.INCORRECT;
        }
        else
        {
            _currentQuestion.Answers[answerId].Status = AnswerStatus.CORRECT;

            if (Test.Count > _questionCount)
            {
                _questionCount++;
                CurrentQuestion = Test[_questionCount];
            }
            else
            {
                //tell view to finish up and move screens
                // show a popup alerting the user that the practise has ended
            }
        }
    }
```

my command class

```
 public class RelayCommand<T>:ICommand
  {
   private readonly Action<T> _executeAction;
   private readonly Func<T, bool> _canExecuteMethod;

   public RelayCommand(Action<T> executeAction)
       :this(executeAction,null)
   {
   }

   public RelayCommand(Action<T> executeAction, Func<T,bool> canExecuteMethod)
   {
       if (executeAction==null)
       {
           throw new ArgumentNullException("executeAction");
       }
       this._executeAction = executeAction;
       this._canExecuteMethod = canExecuteMethod;
   }

   public bool CanExecute(T parameter)
   {
       if (_canExecuteMethod!= null)
       {
           return _canExecuteMethod(parameter);
       }
       return true;
   }

   public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

   public void Execute(T parameter)
   {
       if (_executeAction!= null)
       {
           _executeAction(parameter); 
       }
   }

   public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
   {

       return CanExecute((T)parameter);
      // return true;

   }

   public void Execute(object parameter)
   {

       Execute((T)parameter);
      // _executeAction((T)parameter);
   }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind CommandParameters afaik so why don't you avoid the problem altogether by not passing the SelectedItem as a parameter but instead TwoWay bind it to a SelectedAnswer property on the ViewModel and then access it directly inside your ProcessQuestion command logic